# Objective-C @interface nameofclass (whatisinhere)

Tags: objective-c

I'm looking at NSArray.h which has

```
@interface NSMutableArray : NSArray
```

which I understand. Just below is

```
@interface NSMutableArray (NSExtendedMutableArray)
```

which I do not understand. I want to use the Extended version of this class, but can't figure out how. Just creating an object of class NSExtendedMutableArray doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a language feature called [`categories`](http://macdevelopertips.com/objective-c/objective-c-categories.html).  It's not defining a new class named `NSExtendedMutableArray`; rather, it's defined a new aspect of the `NSMutableArray` class by adding new methods to it.

You can't create an `NSExtendedMutableArray` because there's no such thing, it's just a unique name that only the compiler cares about.  All `NSMutableArray`s in your program support the functionality defined here, so what you probably want to do is just extend `NSMutableArray`, or implement a new category yourself.

Comment: I had no idea this was a thing in Objective-C; I was confused as well. Thanks!